# Does phone CPU have separate integer and floating point compute units that can operate in parallel?

Tags: android, arm, x86-64, cpu-architecture, arm64

On desktop CPU, interleaved integer and float computation (such as with float arrays: updating integer indexes while computing the array value) is faster than all integer compute then all float compute. This is because integer ops and float ops are processed by different parts of the CPU, so they can be processed at the basically same time.

Is it the same for newer phones' CPU and ARM architecture in general?

Comment: Wait, this isn't about SIMD?  Sorry, I misread the title as asking if phones had parallel-integer and parallel-fp (i.e. SIMD) ALUs.

Comment: I understand. You mistook it for (parallel int) and (parallel float), while the question ask parallel (int and float).

Comment: Your premise isn't totally true on most x86-64 CPUs; on both Intel and AMD, you can saturate the front-end with just integer work, and not bottleneck on the back-end.  All you need is enough instruction-level parallelism to not bottleneck on latency; it doesn't matter much whether that's all integer or some integer and some FP.  (Although FP math like addps/subps/fmaps can only run on 2 back-end ports on Sandybridge-family, so that does leave room to mix some integer work.)  Some integer insns compete for the same execution ports as SIMD-integer and SIMD-fp on Intel, not AMD.

Comment: But yes, if you have some FP work to do, mixing in some scalar integer work can get it done nearly for free, especially on Ryzen or Bulldozer.  And maybe even some SIMD-integer, depending which instructions.  Or if your FP code bottlenecks on latency, then there's lots of cycles left in the front-end and back-end.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes mixing integer/fp work together is what I mean. On Intel laptop the performance uplift is noticeable (10-20%), but I wonder if it is the same for phones/ARM cpu

Comment: what did you find when you read the processor documentation?  what part did you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the x86 architecture has already been discussed in the comments, now about ARM:

Basically, this also depends on the processor model used. Most ARM processors have only two pipelines for SIMD calculations. Some instructions can only be executed on one of the two pipelines, but most do not care. This also applies to simple ALU operations such as

- `FADD`, `FSUB`, `FMUL` for floating-point SIMD
- `ADD`, `SUB`, `MUL` for integer SIMD

If this addition, for example, already has a throughput of (maximum) 2 instructions per cycle, this means that both pipelines are fully utilized. So here simple integer instructions are just as fast as floating point instructions. Due to the high throughput, no speed advantage can be achieved by using the pipelines for SIMD or even SISD integer operations instead. Here I assume, of course, that there are no dependencies between the instructions.

In addition to the throughput, the latency of the instructions must also be taken into account: The integer SIMD `ADD` has a maximum latency of 3 cycles, for floating-point `FADD` it is 4 cycles. On the other hand, the non-SIMD `add` only has one cycle latency. The latency indicates the number of cycles after which the result is available at the earliest. If the following instruction is based on the result of the previous one, the throughput is limited and it can be useful to put other instructions in between that use other pipelines, for example the non-SIMD ALU one.

At least that's the case with the Cortex-A72 and Cortex-A76. With the older Cortex-A55 it's a bit more complicated. You can find information in the respective "Software Optimization Guide", for example:

- [Arm® Cortex®-A55 Software Optimization Guide](https://static.docs.arm.com/epm128372/20/arm_cortex_a55_software_optimization_guide_v2.pdf)
- [Arm® Cortex®-A72 Software Optimization Guide](https://static.docs.arm.com/uan0016/a/cortex_a72_software_optimization_guide_external.pdf)
- [Arm® Cortex®-A76 Software Optimization Guide](https://static.docs.arm.com/swog307215/a/Arm_Cortex-A76_Software_Optimization_Guide.pdf)

**Clarification after some comments:** Scalar operations on SIMD registers (using `s0` to `s31`, `d0` to `d31` etc.) and vector operations on them (`v0` to `v31`) always take place on the two SIMD pipelines. Only operations on general-purpose registers (`w0` to `w30`, `wzr`, `wsp`, `x0` to `x31`, `xzr`, `xsp`) run on the two non-SIMD ALU pipelines I0/I1 and the M-Pipeline. That's why, in some cases, one ALU pipeline I0/I1 is also used for address calculation with SIMD instructions.

Comment: All of this is assuming that your FP work has enough ILP to bottleneck on throughput in the first place, of course.  If mixing SIMD-integer and SIMD-fp is a convenient way to have more ILP in one loop body, instead of more loop unrolling, that's a good thing.  Also, I think the question was considering mixing *scalar* integer with FP, not just SIMD-integer.

Comment: For SIMD I understand. But what about scalar int and scalar FP? Can they be processed at the same time in the pipeline ?

Comment: I have added some lines to the post: There is no difference between scalar FP and vector FP in the pipelines used. Both run on the two SIMD pipelines. The use of instructions on general-purpose registers can make sense if there are such dependencies between the SIMD instructions that their latency become important there.